# Creature generator

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, inheritance

Originally posted this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32933050/javascript-classes-am-i-heading-the-right-way), and it was helpfully suggested to post in this forum.

In the past couple of years I've returned part time to programming after a 15 year gap. I was C/UNIX. So, I've picked up PHP, Java and C++ ok, but have struggled with JavaScript.

Finally I think I've found a way to 'create' classes that can inherit and wondered if anyone would care to comment. Here is an example:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <title>Basic</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="d1"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">

function Base( options ) {
    var that = this;
    options = options || {};
    Object.keys( options ).forEach( function( item ) {
        that[item] = options[item];
    });
}

function Creature( options ) {
    this.legs = 4;

    Base.call( this, options );
    console.log("New creature");
}

Creature.prototype.showNumberOfLegs = function() {
    console.log( "Number legs " + this.legs );
};


function Mammal( options ) {
    this.fur = true;
    Creature.call( this, options );

    console.log("New mammal");
}

Mammal.prototype = Object.create( Creature.prototype );

Mammal.prototype.showFur = function() {
    console.log( "Fur " + this.fur );
};

var c = new Creature();
c.showNumberOfLegs();

var m = new Mammal({ legs: 6, fur: false });
m.showNumberOfLegs();
m.showFur();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> but have struggled with JavaScript

Welcome to JavaScript, where all things look fine but are actually half broken. :D

> Finally I think I've found a way to 'create' classes that can inherit

I think there's a saying that goes like "Composition over inheritance". That's because composition is more flexible and doesn't impose hard taxonomies of classes or make you resort to multiple inheritance. See [this video](https://youtu.be/wfMtDGfHWpA) for a detailed comparison.

Now let's go over to your code. Let's just say *for now* that I advocate inheritance. Let's do this!

```
options = options || {};
Object.keys( options ).forEach( function( item ) {
    that[item] = options[item];
});

// to

Object.keys(options || {}).forEach(function(key){
  this[key] = options[key];
}, this);

// to

Object.assign(this, options || {});
```

You can streamline your assignment operation by inlining the defaulting of `options` to an empty object. The context (`this`) can also be provided to the callback of `forEach` via its second argument.

If you can do ES6, there's `Object.assign()` which does the same thing in lesser code. It pretty much looks like jQuery's `$.extend` if you're familiar with it.

---

```
Base.call( this, options );

// to

Base.apply(this, arguments);
```

The reason is that you don't actually know how many arguments you'll potentially provide the constructor. In your code, you assume your only argument is `options`, but that might change. `apply` allows you to pass in an array or array-like object as an argument, spreading it as the `arguments` on the receiving end.

---

You are missing:

```
Creature.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
```

Here's a checklist of what to do when doing prototypal inheritance manually:

- Inherit the parent properties (`Parent.apply(this, arguments`).
- Inherit the parent prototype (`Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype)`)
- Define child properties and their default values
- Define child methods

Comment: It's good to remember that `Object.keys()` is only supported on IE9 and newer. If support for IE8 is required, you need a polyfill or an alternative method.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel The OP did use `forEach` and `Object.create`, so maybe it's safe to say the code is for ES5-compatible browsers.

Comment: Oh, right... Maybe the O.P. may not be aware, since there's nothing saying that IE support isn't a requirement. Now-a-days, I don't even know the amount of bad advices that are around the internet

Comment: `where all things look fine but are actually half broken.` I'd argue it's the other way around; *where all things look broken but are actually just fine*.

Comment: Thanks @JosephtheDreamer, that's a great answer - very helpful. And the video - maybe even more helpful :) I'd just got to that problem with my Pet class ... I shall do some thinking